# ColdFusion Reports

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Is it possible to run reports generated by ColdFusion Report builder on CFMX7?

More explicitly, is it possible to change the report generation engine in CF7 to CF8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is this might be difficult to do.. I recall there being changes in the reporting between CF7 and CF8.. meaning the interfacing between the libraries also evolved.

I have been going back and forth between using report builder and doing html reports where it gets too complicated for CFRB.

Have you considered using a Java Reporting solution?  There are some great libraries out there that might do what you're looking for .. free.

Here's one I am looking at called Jasper Reports

http://java-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting

Comment: Thanks.  After more testing we pretty much came to the same conclusion.  We are going to evaluate the other products.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: No Problem.  There seems to be some interesting posts out there about using JasperReports with CF8.. apparently CF8 has an old version of JR built into cfusion.jar.. This can lead to issues when calling JasperReports which can be worked around by making static calls or using that append and "A" trick in Java with the jar filename.  

My (vague) guess is that Coldfusion Report is using an older version of JasperReports.  I would even wonder if the CFRB is based on a tool like JasperReport's iTools.. both are Java from what I recall.

Let me know how you make out.. I'll be playing with JR soon!

Comment: jasperreports runs great on Railo is that is an option for you.